# Js number sorting higher to lower

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, numbers

I have variables:

```js
    let var1 = 20;
    let var2 = 10;
    let var3 = 40;
    let var4 = 9;
    let var5 = 6;
    let var6 = 51;
```

And i want something that can sort them higher numbers to lower numbers and give me variable names back as sorted.

Example:

```js
    let var5 = 6;
    let var4 = 9;
    let var2 = 10;
    let var1 = 20;
    let var3 = 40;
    let var6 = 51;
```

Is there a code that can do that? (but i want variable names back as sorted)

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with this? It makes absolutely no difference in this case how the variable declarations are ordered.

Comment: Hi Hasan! Is the list of variables known to you and static?

Comment: Sounds like you need an array, rather than random variables.

Comment: or a Map or Set

Comment: @line-o maybe a Map. Not sure a Set is very convenient, as you cannot have duplicates then. But I'd probably go with an array for a start.

Comment: what means *bigger to lower*?

Comment: @Pointy i am trying to make a leaderboard so i am trying to sort points.

Comment: @line-o variable names are known but they are not static.

Comment: @HasanYıldırım then you need an **array** of **objects** that contain some kind of identifier for who "scored" the points, and the number of points, then sort that array. Having separate variables will not work.

Comment: @Pointy I have map by ids like "total1 for user1, total2 for user2"

Comment: Right. You cannot do that with distinct variables as in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want top reassign the values in sorted order, you could take an array with values, sort them and destructure to old variables.

```js
let var1 = 20,
    var2 = 10,
    var3 = 40,
    var4 = 9,
    var5 = 6,
    var6 = 51;

[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6] = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6]
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
```

Comment: While clever, it is very unlikely that this is actually a good solution to whatever problem the OP is actually trying to solve.  Chances are about 98% that they are asking for the wrong solution to whatever the real problem is and you probably know that too.

Comment: What a creative solution.

Comment: I can't change the variables number, i just want to sort them like in my example.

Comment: @HasanYıldırım, you want only to sort the appearance of the variables in the code?

Comment: Of course not. Like i will give code my variables, then code will run give me the list:
var6 - biggest
var3 - 
var 1 -
var 2 -
var 4 -
var 5 - lowest

Comment: @HasanYıldırım, why not take an array?

Comment: @jfriend00 while I agree with your point, this answer does provide a possible solution to the OP's question. The real-world problem that the OP is trying to solve would be out of scope within this context.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments of the OP

```js
let scores = [
  { "id": 1, "score": 2 },
  { "id": 2, "score": 23 },
  { "id": 3, "score": 12 },
  { "id": 4, "score": 2 },
  { "id": 5, "score": 299 }
]

let leaderBoard = scores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)
```

Comment: Thx very much trying now.

Comment: Shouldn't be it `b.score-a.score` and for some reason it's not changing the listing.

Comment: leaderBoard will now hold the objects in sorted order.
And yes b.score - a.score might be what you want :)

Comment: This looks like a better way to go for the actual problem the user is working with.